# /testfor for item enchantment

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I have now is:

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"diamond_pickaxe"}]}
```

How can I use the `/testfor` command to test a specific slot for a specific item that is enchanted?

Comment: What enchantment do you want to add?

Answer (score 1):

All item data other than the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, and `Slot` tags must be placed within a single `tag` compound. The `ench` list holds enchantments, with `id` short tag stating the numerical enchantment ID while the `lvl` short tag specifies the level of enchantment.

You may be interested in the `SelectedItem` compound, which holds a copy of the player's currently-held item. This way you do not need to check for every hotbar slot for an item.

For example, the following looks for a diamond pickaxe with Sharpness of any level:

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_pickaxe",tag:{ench:[{id:16s}]}}}
```

The following looks for Sharpness 1:

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_pickaxe",tag:{ench:[{id:16s,lvl:1s}]}}}
```

---

As a side-note, if you intend to target the player(s) who match the data, you do **not** want to use `/testfor`, because after detecting a matching player there is nothing that tells you who to target. You will want to use a command like `/scoreboard` instead, which allows you to assign a label to entities that match the specified NBT data.

Example using 1.9's "tags" feature:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HoldingItem] remove HoldingItem
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!HoldingItem] add HoldingItem {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_pickaxe",tag:{ench:[{id:16s,lvl:1s}]}}}
/say @a[tag=HoldingItem]
```